# Querying a rails db column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm looking for a similar way to query the database [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36094111/how-to-return-an-array-of-clients-with-include) but struggling how to go about what I want.

I'm not just looking for the answer, I also seek where do you find the methods to use. I have searched for postgres db query, rails db query but nothing shows up that matches what I want, or even close.

```
foo = "a,b,c,d"
b.bar #=> "b,d,a,f,z" Code shorten for the B Class.

B.where('bar like ?', "%#{foo}")
```

I know that returns nothing. I want if any of `foo`'s value is included in `b.bar` column, then return it.

If `foo = "a"`, I would get a result but `foo` can have more than one values.

**Im using Ruby 2.2.5. Rails 5. DB: PostgreSQL**

Will upgrade to Ruby 2.3 if code is much simple.

Comment: This can be done by using multiple `LIKE` condition combine with `OR` or by a regexp expression. But is it really worth it? There kind of queries are usually slow, because they cannot use an index. A much better solution would be to normalize the data and have `foos` table with a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association to `B`. You might want to consider changing your database schema.

Comment: I was thinking the same. I may need to change the schema like you've said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do some pre-work before actual querying, starting with constructing `like` conditions for each item in the delimited with `,` list and then chaining them with logical `or`:

```
conditions = b.bar.split(',').map{|x| B.arel_table[:bar].matches("%#{x}%") }

B.where conditions.reduce(:or)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to find matches for a field in an array:

```
B.where(bar: ["a", "b", "c"])
```

That will use a [SQL IN operator](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-in/)